# Scala compilers complains about "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition" when asking for a function in the second parameters set

Tags: function, scala, compiler-construction, functional-programming, signature

This seems strange. The following will compile fine:

```
def foo(s: String) = "balsh"
def foo(s: String)(s2: String) = "kahsd"
```

If I make the second parameter implicit, it still compiles fine and all.

However, the following will not:

```
def foo(s: String) = "bjda"
def foo(s: String)(fun: String => String) = fun(s)
```

^that one will not compile due to "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition".

My original thought was that the way Scala was converting functions to Java was causing the signatures of the two to be the same. However, looking at the compile coded (for the second function only since it would not compile with both) with javap, you would see that such a function is actually converted into:

```
public java.lang.String foo(java.lang.String, scala.Function1);
```

So a separate method is created, with a different signature. So why is this failing to compile?

Now to make matters even more confusing, the following actually compiles fine!

```
def foo(s: String) = "bjda"
def foo(s: String, fun: String => String) = fun(s)
```

If you make the function part of the first set of parameters, then everything is fine!

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT:

So I just tried this:

```
object main {
  def write(s: String) = "sasd"
  def write(s: String)(implicit s2: String => String) = s2(s)
}
```

I simply made the function in the second parameter implicit. Lo and behold, this compiles.

This is the java code it produces:

```
public final class main$ extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final main$ MODULE$;
    public static {};
    public java.lang.String write(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String write(java.lang.String, scala.Function1);
}
```

This is what I would have expected from the original one without the implicit!

Comment: when you say "that one will not compile", what are you calling `foo` with?

Comment: @gourlaysama I'm not calling anything. Just compiling. Simply call scalac on a file with that content.

Comment: which version of scala are you using? I tried compiling your `object main` both with *and* without the `implicit` in front of `s2` and both of them compile fine (with 2.10.2, and 2.9.2 too).

Comment: Scala code runner version 2.10.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL. I just recopied that text, pasted it into a new file and ran scalac on it again (just in case I copied it wrong here). It still compiled to the main$ class above. Not sure why yours isn't compiling.

Comment: mine is compiling fine. That's the point, I do not get any compile error with any of your code: [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/gourlaysama/767a752ee7b19f904cce). Where do you get that *ambiguous reference to overloaded definition*?

Comment: Err, no don't use the REPL. Actually write a file and run `scalac` on it. I also tried it in the REPL and I also was not getting any errors. I think REPL reads these things differently, or something. If you don't like `scalac`, an IDE (presentation compiler) would also show the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess there is no way for the compiler to select between the two as they are really just differing in return types. It is not possible to dispatch based on the return type of a function only the parameters. Think of the signatures like this:

```
def foo(s: String): String
def foo(s: String): String => String
```

Not sure why you get it to work if you make it implicit, I get the same error (as I would expect).

```
def foo(s: String, fun: String => String)
```

on the other hand has a different parameter list which is possible to dispatch to.

Comment: Btw, when I said implicit, I meant the non-function one (the first foo). And it does compile for me. And now, I tried to make the function implicit on the second parameter set, and, lo and behold, it compile......I'm so confused.

Comment: this looks wrong. Shouldn't the equivalent of `def foo(s: String)(fun: String => String): String` be `def foo(s: String): (String => String) => String`? Not that there is such equivalence, there is a real difference between a method returning a function and a method with 2 parameter lists...

Comment: Well there shouldn't be a difference. Currying means that a function can take one parameter (in Scala's case, a list of parameters) and return a function that can take the remaining parameters. I don't know how Scala implements currying but, semantically speaking, a function returning a function and a function taking 2 sets of parameters should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to avoid the implicit hack, here's another way:

```
def foo(s: String) = "balsh"
def foo(t: String)(s2: String) = "kahsd"
```

where the second function's parameter name is changed to something different. Then when you want the first one:

```
foo(s = "foo")
```

and when you want the second:

```
foo(t = "foo")
```